# Set default value to an existing item in DataTable for ComboBox

Tags: c#, datatable, combobox

I use ComboBox as the Dropdown, and I assign a DataTable as the DataSource. How to set default value to an existing item in DataTable (I don't want to create a new item) and show that in drawdown (ComboBox)?

Here is my C# code

```
ComboBox statusDDL = new ComboBox();
DataTable allStatus = dataLayer.getAllStatus();
statusDDL.DataSource = allStatus;
statusDDL.DisplayMember = "Status";
statusDDL.ValueMember = "TaskStatusID";
```

My DataTable has 2 columns and 6 rows, which are "statusID" and "Status". I want to set the default value to statusID = 2 and Status = "In Progress".

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the statusID =2 in your allStatus datatable
and then set that index to the selected index property.

```
statusDDL.SelectedIndex = <position of statusid 2>;
```

Comment: How do you get the index of the statusID = 2? Is there a specific function to call?